# How do I get the auto number after an INSERT in Ms Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following query in VBA:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO table (value) VALUES ('example')"
```

( with an auto incremented primary key called `id`)

How can I get the auto incremented id generated by this insert?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you're looking for:

```
@@Identity
```

It's similar to SCOPE_IDENTITY in T-SQL.  Check out this article for more info:

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/54/Getting-the-identity-of-the-most-recently-added-record

Comment: Wow, I did not know this! I've been doing SELECT Max(Field) for ever. I notice the samples are ADO.NET, does this also work in classic ADO?